# How can I use Icons from material-ui icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I want to use an icon inside an iconbutton like this:

```
<IconButton >
    <SearchIcon/>
</IconButton>
```

I installed @material-ui/icons in my package.json and have the following imports:

```
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SearchIcon';
```

Now I get the error message:

Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/SearchIcon'

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you done "npm install"?

Comment: yes, I've already tried "npm install"

Comment: It's `import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search`

Comment: You mention you installed the icons; Did you install it like: `@material-ui/core/Icon` or `@material-ui/icons`?

Comment: I installed it like "@material-ui/icons", but the different import method without appending Icon was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to append the name with `Icon`, just use the name i.e. `/Search` (see [examples](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svg-material-icons)).